# Is there a way to run Windows CE 6.0 emulator at a 1024 * 600 resolution?

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-ce, emulation

We are creating an embedded application for Windows CE 6.0 for which we do not have the hardware yet.  We would like to be able to run in emulation mode at a resolution of 1024 * 600 to develop as that is the screen resolution of the hardware we will be using.

It appears that the highest resolution that the Windows CE 6.0 emulator supports is 800 * 600.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately no - or at least not easily. The emulator's video driver doesn't have enough memory to run at 1024x600.

It *may* be possible to alter this (I say may because I've never tried it).  You have the display driver for the emulator's display driver (%WINCEROOT%\PLATFORM\DEVICEEMULATOR\src\drivers\display\lcd) and it looks like s3c2410x_lcd.cpp at around line 260 sets up the display size.

The question here is does the emulator shell application limit the sizes that you can pass in here, or does it have some hard-coded limits?  I don't know the answer to that, but you do have all the tools to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the boot args in my OAL to 1024x600 so that the LCD driver reads those values in the lines that Chris suggested be modified, but I just get a ton of exceptions when it runs.  I tried increasing some of the buffers in the LCD and OAL code, but no dice.  It appears that the device emulator shell has a 1 MB limit on the video memory.  You can see this if you try to configure it for 800x600x32.

So is this 1 MB limit really in the device emulator or in the OS that is running in it?  Does anyone have any suggestions for how I could determine this?

An alternative solution might be to try to implement 8bpp if you don't care so much about the color depth.  There are some definitions in s3c2410x_lcd.h that suggest 8bpp is supported, although the OAL defaults to 16bpp if 16, 24, or 32 is not specified.  Maybe I'll give that a shot tomorrow.